# creating a matrix from multiple pandas data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have basically no experience with pandas and I'm trying to force myself to use it more.

I'm trying to join the "count" of multiple data frames based on a specific column to create a count matrix. I usually do this with good old python dictionaries, but if there's a simple way to do this with pandas, I'd be interested in learning.

I have multiple data frames. They are not equal in size. GeneID and geneName are basically the same thing. Just different ways of identifying the gene.

My data frames look like this:

Data frame1:

```
     geneID  geneName  count
0    A123    ABC       202
1    B456    DEF       30
2    C789    GHI       265
```

Data frame2:

```
     geneID  geneName  count
0    X999    FOO       700
1    B456    DEF       606
2    C789    GHI       777
```

If a gene name/ gene ID is not present in any of the data frames, it should have the count value of "0" in the matrix file.

Here is the desired result after joining counts:

```
     geneID  geneName  df1   df2   df3 ...
0    A123    ABC       202   0
1    B456    DEF       30    606
2    C789    GHI       265   777
3    X999    FOO       0     700
```

Thanks in advance for any solutions, and any pandas learning tips!

Answer (score 1):

Try `pd.concat`:

```
pd.concat([d.set_index(['geneID','geneName']).rename(columns={'count':f'df{i}'})
           for i,d in enumerate([df1,df2])], axis=1
         ).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
                   df0    df1
geneID geneName              
A123   ABC       202.0    0.0
B456   DEF        30.0  606.0
C789   GHI       265.0  777.0
X999   FOO         0.0  700.0
```

---

Or `concat` then `pivot_table`:

```
(pd.concat([d.assign(col=f'df{i}') for i,d in enumerate([df1,df2])])
   .pivot_table(index=['geneID','geneName'], columns='col', 
                values='count', fill_value=0)
)
```

Or a similar approach with option `key` in `concat`:

```
(pd.concat([df1,df2], keys=['df1','df2'])
   .reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
   .set_index(['geneID','geneName'],append=True)
   ['count']
   .unstack(level=0, fill_value=0)
)
```

Comment: Thanks a million! "concat" was what I was missing haha. This helped a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way:

```
concatdict = {'df1':df1,'df2':df2}
df3 = pd.concat(concatdict).reset_index(level=1,drop=True).set_index(['geneID','geneName'],append=True)['count'].unstack(level=0).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

or

```
d = {'df1':df1,'df2':df2}

pd.concat(d).set_index(['geneID','geneName'],append=True).squeeze().unstack(level=0).fillna(0).droplevel(0).reset_index()
```

or

```
c = ['geneID','geneName']

pd.concat([df1.set_index(c).squeeze(),df2.set_index(c).squeeze()],keys = ['df1','df2'],axis=1).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I needed to build up on!